# embed swf file into email and send in C#

Tags: email, flash, embed

I have .net user control which will send email on click of button. Now, in email I want to send swf file embeded into the email. following is the code. But it does not show swf file in email.

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string body = "Dear Balvignan Team,\r\n\r\n";

        if (txtComment.Text != null)
        {
            body = body + "Comment: " + txtComment.Text;
        }

        body=body + "<object classid='clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000' ";
        body=body + "codebase='http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,19,0' width='425' height='300' align='middle'>";
        body=body+ "<param name='movie' value='http://mydomain.com/images/ecards/CardCreative629.swf' />";
        body=body + "<param name='quality' value='high' />";
        body=body +  "<param name='wmode' value='opaque' />";
        body = body + "<embed src='http://mydomain.com/images/ecards/CardCreative629.swf' width='425' height='300' align='middle' quality='high' pluginspage='http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' wmode='opaque'  ></embed>";
        body = body + "</object>";
        if (SendEmail(txtEmail.Text.Trim(), "Comment", body, true) == true)
        {

            lblContactAcknowledge.Text = "Thank You For <br />Submitting comment.";

            lblContactAcknowledge.Visible = true;
            PnlTalkToUs.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            lblContactAcknowledge.Visible = false;
            PnlTalkToUs.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

SendEmail(string From, string Subject, string Message, bool IsHTML) is function which sends email.

Answer (score 1):

That's because basically no email clients support Flash.

Here is a [blog article](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/1974/the-truth-about-1/) covering this topic.

You can embed static images instead, and some clients (or webmail interfaces) allow animated ones aswell. But you should not expect a client to show flash content, and therefore shouldn't use it in emails either.

Comment: ok. but is there any other way so that I can send swf object in email?

Comment: Like I wrote in the first sentence, if no email clients display flash content then you can't get them to either. Did you never wonder why spam emails never contain animated and blinking flash content? I'm actually glad that email clients don't support this.